# check event argument in event handler c#

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

I want to keep track of the argument passed in argument in event subscription, so that I can after select/narrow down my invokes.

```
public List<Tags> _toSpecificTagSubscribed = new List<Tags>();
private event Action<Tags> _onSpecificTagEvent;
public event Action<Tags> OnSpecificTagEvent {
    add { 
        _onSpecificTagCollision += value; 
        if (!_toSpecificTagSubscribed.Contains(<TagArgumentValue>))
            _toSpecificTagSubscribed.Add(<TagArgumentValue>); 
        }
        remove { _onSpecificTagEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```

See the `<TagArgumentValue>`. That is passed in in the event itself on the subscription so I wonder how to access it. Would be kind of `value.<TagArgumentValue>`, meaning the value of the argument passed into the event.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're confusing "the information provided when the event is raised" with "the information provided within the event handler".

An `Action<Tags>` can do anything with the `Tags` it is provided. It *might* choose to only respond to certain tags, but it's just arbitrary code.

If you want to have a way of subscribing just for a specific tag, you'd need that to be part of the subscription information, e.g.

```cs
public void AddTagHandler(Tags tag, Action<Tags> handler)
```

You could potentially use a `Dictionary<Tags, Action<Tags>>` to keep track of the handlers subscribed for any given tag.

(You might also want to check that `Tags` is the right name for the type - it *looks* like it should represent a single tag rather than a collection of tags, given how you're using it.)

Comment: Its precisely as you say. Regarding the name, might not be that innapropiate as `Tags` is an enum type, so what is passed in is  a Tag value from the possible `Tags`. I'd have to think about though. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay: If each value is meant to be a single tag, it should be called `Tag`. If a single value is a bitwise combination of potentially multiple tags, then `Tags` is appropriate and it should have a `[Flags]` attribute applied to it - but that would make the logic here considerably more complex.

Comment: I do agree, I dont find it that misleading because Im used to my code, but it is :)